# Why is the toolbar button disabled in my Visual Studio extension?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I've written a Visual Studio 2010 extension. It's a VS Package (in a .VSIX) file. It's got a toolbar, which has a single button on it.

The button is never enabled. I've looked at the MenuAndCommands VS SDK example and, as far as I can tell, I'm not doing anything different.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work now: could be one of two things:

1. I didn't put the package GUID on the `<Commands>` node in the .VSCT file.
2. It appears that the .VSCT file is not always built when it should be. A rebuild all later, and it appears to be working...

Comment: I find whenever I touch the .vsct I need to rebuild the whole solution. Just F5 doesn't cut it.

Comment: Thanks for this command, I too forgot to add the package GUID to the Commands node, this solved my problem too

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this... problem was I had disabled the buttons in the vsct file, commenting out the **DefaultDisabled** solved the problem:

```
<Button guid="guidXYZCmdSet" id="XYZmd" priority="0x0007" type="Button">
<Parent guid="guidSXYZCmdSet" id="guidSXYZMenuGroup" />
<Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpVS" />
<!--<CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
<CommandFlag>DefaultDisabled</CommandFlag>
<CommandFlag>DefaultInvisible</CommandFlag>-->
```